# Overflow scroll not working on container div

Tags: scroll, overflow

I have a wide iframe  on a page that I want to make horizontally scrollable. In order to achieve this I put it inside a div and used CSS to make the div the scrollable element.

It all worked fine for a while but I must have altered something and broken the functionality. Nothing that I do seems to make it work again. The div displays fine but the ifame content is cut off (as though I have overflow-x set to hidden). If I set overflow-x to auto no scrollbar appears even though the content is too wide for the div. If I set overflow-x to scroll then the scrollbar appears but is not active. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```html
<div class="PopularTravelAccessories Centre">
  <h3 style="color:#e47911; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; line-height:0.2;">Title</h3>
  <iframe src="/path-to-iframe.php?" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
 .PopularTravelAccessories
  {
   width:100%;
   max-width: 500px;
   position:relative;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: hidden;  /*Remove vertical scroll bar*/
   border-top:1px;
   border-top-style:dashed;
   border-top-color:#999999;
   margin-top:10px;
   border-bottom:1px;
   border-bottom-style:dashed;
   border-bottom-color:#999999;
   margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  
  .PopularTravelAccessories iframe
   {
    width: 100%;
    height:215px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I stumbled upon the solution, all I needed to do was remove the scrolling="no" from the iframe. Not quite sure why that would affect the scrolling on the div but it worked for me.